# I need a function which is the opposite or inverse of NETWORKDAYS in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

NETWORKDAYS returns the number of days between two dates.  I have a Start Date and the number of Business Days, and I need to return the End Date.  (Or I need to provide the End Date and number of business days and return the Start Date).  Is there an Excel function to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the [WORKDAY function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/workday-HP005209339.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Think you are looking for WORKDAY(start_date,days)